# Generate a 2D boolean array from tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I generate a 2D boolean array using a list of tuples that shows the indices of the True values?

For example I have the following list of tuples:

```
lst = [(0,1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 3), (2,1)]
```

What I do is, I first generate an array of False's:

```
arr = np.repeat(False, 12).reshape(3, 4)
```

Then, iterate over the list to assign True values:

```
for tup in lst:
    arr[tup] = True
print(arr)
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

It seems like a common use case to me so I was wondering if there is a built-in method for this, without the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip(*...)` is a handy way of 'transposing' a list of lists (or tuples). And  `A[x,y]` is the same as `A[(x,y)]`.

```
In [397]: lst = [(0,1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 3), (2,1)]

In [398]: tuple(zip(*lst))    # make a tuple of tuples (or lists)
Out[398]: ((0, 0, 1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0, 3, 1))

In [399]: A=np.zeros((3,4),dtype=bool)  # make an array of False

In [400]: A[tuple(zip(*lst))] = True  # assign True to the 5 values

In [401]: A
Out[401]: 
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [multidimensional indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) for this:

```
>>> lst = np.array(lst)
>>> arr = np.repeat(False, 12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> arr[lst[:,0], lst[:,1]] = True
>>> arr
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: What does `lst[:,0]` mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [`NumPy's linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) that works for tuples of any lengths intended to generate multi-dimensional arrays -

```
# Convert list of indices to a 2D array version
idx = np.array(lst)

# Decide on the shape of output array based on the extents, then initialize
shp = idx.max(0)+1
out = np.zeros(shp,dtype=bool)

# Using np.put insert 1s in out at places specified by linear indices version
np.put(out,np.ravel_multi_index(idx.T,shp),1)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [54]: lst
Out[54]: [(0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 3)]

In [55]: out
Out[55]: 
array([[[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[ True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```