# Editing Large Matrix Python

Tags: python, matrix

I want to make a 34x34 Matrix consisting of entirely zeroes and ones. I have an array that lists the coordinates where all of the ones should go but don't know how to use it. The array looks like this:

0 1 1

0 2 1

0 3 1

1 1 1

where the first number in each row is the x coordinate, the second number in each row is the y coordinate, and the third number is the desired value (always 1).

I tried to create a blank matrix using Matrix=numpy.zeros(34,34) but I don't know how to change the desired values all at once.

Any idea how to take a matrix and change multiple values at once?

Comment: make a list pairs (coords where the ones should be), loop over it, and set matrix[i][j] = 1 for every (i, j) in the list

Comment: What is zeros? Is it numpy.zeros? If so, please add the tag. Also, please create a small sample (for example 5x5) showing what data structure you have for coordinates, and what the output should be.

Comment: Also related: [Generate a 2D boolean array from tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36989390/2285236)

Comment: Just added an example of the array with the coordinates. Also, could you be more specific in what you mean by making a list of pairs?

Comment: What you mean by "array that lists the coordinates"? Is it numpy array? Is it list of tuples? Somthing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's work:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,2,1],[0,3,1],[1,1,1]])
m = np.zeros([5,5])
for i in range(len(a)):
   m[a[i][0],a[i][1]] = a[i][2]  # Or = 1 if that's always the case
```

And the m matrix is:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: @ForrestB Great :)