# Python: How to edit 2d array by inputting a list of coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a 2 dimensional array in python, `someArray = np.zeros([10,10])`, and I have a list of coordinates, `listOfCoordinates = [(0,0), (4,4), (9,9)]`, is there any nice syntax for updating the values of the area according to the coordinates in the list?

Something like `someArray[listOfCoordinates] = 5` ?

the list of coordinates doesn't have to contain tuples. I tried doing it with a list of lists and with tuples and neither worked.

Comment: This seems always strange to me but numpy works the other way: You need to pass two tuples: `(0, 4, 9)`  and `(0, 4, 9)`. Here I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989390/generate-a-2d-boolean-array-from-tuples)

Comment: I see. Thanks for that! I'll mark it as a duplicate.